# i have change the margins when i printer crystal report in visual basic 2005

Tags: vb.net, printing, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2005, margins

I've designed crystal Report to print the label small size and no printer machine especially so when I try Print Crystal Report from inside the crystal Report itself shows very well and I also coordinated but when the program is executed and I print the report when implementation is printed and tilted (change the margins of the report)and not, as you design
What problem do you think and how the solution
Thank you

Comment: I ran into this issue when working on an application to print out ID cards for student

Answer (score 1):

In your crystal report go to the `File => Page Setup` and then set all margins to 0. Now try it. You can hold <kbd>Alt-f-g</kbd>.

Comment: This is the only way. Crystal will define your margins based on the print you attemp to print to. If you set it to zero and place your information where you want it, it will hold it's place.

Comment: thank you I've these steps but to no avail Only when the top is changed = 0.20 This problem is resolved –

Answer (score 1):

change your setup margins and change them,it depends on to your printer settings,maybe you need to change it to zero or 0.20 or others.

Answer (score 0):

Also, to change the margins programmatically you can use this:

```
        yourReportObject.PrintOptions.ApplyPageMargins(New CrystalDecisions.Shared.PageMargins(0, 0, 0, 0))
```